# Get Latest Updated from a column of folder IDs

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, formula

Hello I have a column with a list of Google Drive folder links and I would like to get latest updated date of all the files contained in the folders.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnlgl.png)

By looking around I was able to build the following scripts which works fine by giving me the list of all the files contained in the folder and their latest update.

```
function onOpen() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var menuItems = [
    {name: 'UpdateCheck', functionName: 'files'},
  ]; 
  spreadsheet.addMenu('Menu', menuItems);
}


function files() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var result  = ui.prompt("Paste the ID of Google Drive Folder");
  var folderId = result.getResponseText();

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  var output = []; 
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    output.push([file.getName(), file.getLastUpdated()]);
  }
  output.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a[0] == b[0] ? 0 : a[0] < b[0] ? -1 : 1;
  });
   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet().getRange(2, 1, output.length, output[0].length).setValues(output);
```

However I have to use the UI to open each link, copy and paste the ID from the URL in the input field. I would like to just read the column range, get the IDs from the strings without duplicates and run my script and have my result in a new tab. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your current situation and your goal are as follows.

- You have a sheet that the folder links are put to the column "D" in your providing image.

  [image]
- You want to retrieve the folder ID from the links and want to retrieve the filename and the value of `getLastUpdated()` of all files in the folders.
- You want to put the retrieved data on a new sheet.

#### Modified script:

Please set the sheet names of `srcSheetName` and `dstSheetName`.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var srcSheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the source sheet name.
  var dstSheetName = "Sheet2"; // Please set the destination sheet name.

  // Retrieve folder links from "D2:D" and check the duplication.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(srcSheetName);
  var folderIds = [...new Set(sheet.getRange("D2:D" + sheet.getLastRow()).getRichTextValues().flatMap(([d]) => {
    var url = d.getLinkUrl();
    if (url && /^https:\/\/drive\.google\.com\/drive\/folders\/.+/.test(url)) {
      return [url.split("/")[5].trim()];
    }
    return [];
  }))];
  
  // Create an array for putting to sheet.
  var res = folderIds.flatMap(id => {
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(id);
    var files = folder.getFiles();
    var temp = [];
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      temp.push([file.getName(), file.getLastUpdated()]);
    }
    return temp;
  });
  
  // Put the array to the destination sheet.
  ss.insertSheet(dstSheetName).getRange(1, 1, res.length, 2).setValues(res);
}
```

#### About some unclear points, I guessed as follows.

- I couldn't understand the format of folder links in the cells. In this modification, I guessed that the folder link is like `https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/###`.
- I couldn't understand `get the IDs from the strings without duplicates`. In this modification, the duplication of retrieved folder IDs is checked.

#### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
- [insertSheet(sheetName)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertsheetsheetname)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

### Added:

From the following your replying,

> Quick question, when I run it I get an Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFolderById on object DriveApp at line `var res = folderIds.flatMap(id => {     var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(id);` it's solvable or should I open another thread?

> the folder link was indeed incorrect instead of https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/### the format was https://drive.google.com/corp/drive/u/0/folders/####?resourcekey=#### so I correct the code with /^https://drive.google.com/corp/drive/u/0/folders/.+/.test(url)) {       return [url.split("/")[8].trim()]; but now I get 1CHKEThZJ0P-ISv0g0MoGjCCqdZuuJJyA?resourcekey=0-1gzYTJvJv1XDwF2Hx4HvEQ and I need to find a way to get rid of everything right before the "?"

For this, I modified my proposed script as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var srcSheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the source sheet name.
  var dstSheetName = "Sheet2"; // Please set the destination sheet name.

  // Retrieve folder links from "D2:D" and check the duplication.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(srcSheetName);
  var folderIds = [...new Set(sheet.getRange("D2:D" + sheet.getLastRow()).getRichTextValues().flatMap(([d]) => {
    var url = d.getLinkUrl();
    if (url) {
      if (/^https:\/\/drive\.google\.com\/drive\/folders\/.+/.test(url)) {
        return [url.split("/")[5].trim()];
      } else if (/^https:\/\/drive\.google\.com\/.+\/drive\/u\/0\/folders\/.+/.test(url)) {
        return [url.split("/")[8].trim().split("?")[0]];
      }
    }
    return [];
  }))];
  
  // Create an array for putting to sheet.
  var res = folderIds.flatMap(id => {
    try {
      var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(id);
      var files = folder.getFiles();
      var temp = [];
      while (files.hasNext()) {
        var file = files.next();
        temp.push([file.getName(), file.getLastUpdated()]);
      }
      return temp;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log({id, msg: e.message});
    }
  });
  
  // Put the array to the destination sheet.
  ss.insertSheet(dstSheetName).getRange(1, 1, res.length, 2).setValues(res);
}
```

- By this modification, 2 kinds of URLs like `https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/###` and `https://drive.google.com/corp/drive/u/0/folders/####?resourcekey=####` can be used, and when an error occurs when the files are retrieved from the folder, you can see the folder ID at the log. And, the script is not stopped.

Comment: Thank you, This is exactly what I meant, your deductions made in the unclear points are correct. Quick question, when I run it I get an Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFolderById on object DriveApp at line `var res = folderIds.flatMap(id => {
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(id);` it's solvable or should I open another thread?

Comment: @user14160585 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new issue of `Unexpected error`, unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. When I tested my proposed script, no error occurs. I'm worried that in that case, `id` might be invalid. So, for this, I added one more sample script in my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @Tainake thank you for the clarification, the  folder link was indeed incorrect instead of `https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/###` the format was `https://drive.google.com/corp/drive/u/0/folders/####?resourcekey=####` so I correct the code with  `/^https:\/\/drive\.google\.com\/corp\/drive\/u\/0\/folders\/.+/.test(url)) {
      return [url.split("/")[8].trim()];` but now I get 1CHKEThZJ0P-ISv0g0MoGjCCqdZuuJJyA?resourcekey=0-1gzYTJvJv1XDwF2Hx4HvEQ and I need to find a way to get rid of everything right before the "?"

Comment: @user14160585 Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I couldn't notice about your URL like `https://drive.google.com/corp/drive/u/0/folders/####?resourcekey=####`. I deeply apologize for this. For your replying, I modified the script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize agin.

Comment: Outstanding work @Tanaike Thanks!

Comment: @user14160585 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.